# File upload in chunks via http post in java on android

Tags: java, android, networking

I am asked to send a file using http post. The file should be sent in chunks of 1 mb. I looked through this code [IntentService to upload a file](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Core-Class/extendsIntentServicetouploadafile.htm) and it looks like I could use it in my case. However, I have to supply the starting byte of the chunk I am sending in URL as a parameter. Thus I am not sure how to accomplish it. Should I instantiate a new connection for every chunk with the new url? Or can I use the stream method and somehow change the url before the chunk is written to the outputstream ?

Comment: What do you mean with chuncks? Is all during one http connection? Ore one connection per chunck? You should ask the one who gave you this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by using MultipartEntity. Following code will help you understand.

```
    final int cSize = 1024 * 1024; // size of chunk
    File file = new File("path to file");
    final long pieces = file.length()/cSize // used to return file length.

    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(endpoint);

    BufferedInputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

    for (int i= 0; i< pieces; i++) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[cSize];

        if(stream.read(buffer) ==-1)
          break;

        MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
        entity.addPart("chunk_id", new StringBody(String.valueOf(i))); //Chunk Id used for identification.
        request.setEntity(entity);
        ByteArrayInputStream arrayStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer);

        entity.addPart("file_data", new InputStreamBody(arrayStream, filename));

        HttpClient client = app.getHttpClient();
        client.execute(request);
    }
```

Comment: @greenapps i have added some comments to code to make it more clear.

Comment: `pieces = file.length()` that should be `pieces=file.length()/cSize;`. `stream.skip(i* cSize);`. That statement should be removed.  `valueOf(id)`. Better would be `valueOf(i);`.

Comment: `stream.read(buffer);` you should check the return value. `pieces` will not include the last piece of the file so that will go missing.

Comment: if i add pieces=file.length()/cSize; insted it will send same chunk again and again.

Comment: You are completely wrong. If pieces would be equal to file.length() the for loop would be executed file.length times. So more than several millon times. Is that what you want? You apparently never tested that code.

Comment: @greenapps I am using it on my project. and you are right it. i will change it to pieces=file.length()/cSize; but this part stream.skip(i* cSize); shold be there is in it ?if not id is going to change.but chunk data remain the same.

Comment: My god. Why do i have to repeat things? All i said  still comes true.

Comment: @greenapps sorry for making you pissed off. i will make the changes. cool man

Comment: I accept it as a right answer, although I did not use this code specifically, it is a right approach

Comment: @MikhailKim No it isn't. 1. This sends multiple *requests*, not multiple chunks within one request. 2. It ignores the result returned by `read()` unless it is -1. 3. the whole thing is redundant given that `HttpURLConnection` already has chunked transfer mode built-in. 4. It also doesn't compile in its present form. Nothing right about that approach whatsoever.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `URL` and `HttpURLConnection` and call `setChunkedTransferMode()` with the desired chunk size.

You don't need to set the start byte, unless there is something you haven't told us.

Comment: How about if there is a crash due to connectivity, how will we resume from the last place where the crash occurred? I am talking about resume control.

Comment: Just set the appropriate header value on the `URLConnection`, and seek to the same place in the input before you start transferring.